# Programmatically getting the value of the checkboxes in a SPList

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

Does anyone know how to get the value of the checkboxes associate for each row in a SPList? The checkbox I am refering to are the one that you can enable in tabular view.

I cannot seem to find any references to access the checkbox within the following classes:

SPListItem
SPListItemCollection
SPView
SPList

Any help would be appreciated.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
SPListItem listItem = // retrieve your list ;


var YourStringValue = listItem["YourYesNoField"].ToString().ToLower();
```

Return "true" or "false" string values

OR

```
var YourBooleanValue = (bool)listItem["YourYesNoField"];
```

Return True or False boolean values